# How to use sed to delete between third underscore and a comma?

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to remove the text from every line of a csv between the third underscore and the first comma.

I've been able to get everything past the third underscore deleted, and I've tried limiting the deletion by bracketing this deletion with a pattern range between an underscore and comma, but it doesn't seem to work as I'd hope.

I've tried the following:

```
sed '/_/,/,/ s/^\([^_]*\(_[^_]*\)\{2\}\).*/\1/'<Initial.csv >Final.csv

A_G_F_Triple 1,0.001079516,0.000763178,0.001008407,0.001695147
A_G_D_cluster 2,0.002292753,0.001215668,0.001070863,0.001350103
A_P_Z_Home 3,0.001066035,0.002260941,0.002276146,0.002331612
```

I'd hope to get an output of the following:

```
A_G_F,0.001079516,0.000763178,0.001008407,0.001695147
A_G_D,0.002292753,0.001215668,0.001070863,0.001350103
A_P_Z,0.001066035,0.002260941,0.002276146,0.002331612
```

But the actual output is:

```
A_G_F
A_G_D
A_P_Z
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
sed 's/^\([^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*\)_[^,]*/\1/'
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `\([^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*\)` - Group 1: 0+ chars other than `_`, `_`, 0+ chars other than `_`, `_` and 0+ chars other than `_`
- `_`  - an underscore
- `[^,]*` - 0 or more chars other than `,`

See an [online `sed`  demo](https://ideone.com/Vlysqc):

```
s="A_G_F_Triple 1,0.001079516,0.000763178,0.001008407,0.001695147
A_G_D_cluster 2,0.002292753,0.001215668,0.001070863,0.001350103
A_P_Z_Home 3,0.001066035,0.002260941,0.002276146,0.002331612"
sed 's/^\([^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*\)_[^,]*/\1/' <<< "$s"
```